# Plotting Binary dependent variable against continuous independent variable for exploratory analysis

Tags: r, scatter-plot

Is it possible to plot a binary response variable against a continuous variable in order to assess their relationship?

I want to plot a scatter plot of something of the same ilk...

Thank you

Comment: You probably want something like a boxplot - possibly with added jitter to visualise the individual points. e.g. https://scriptsandstatistics.wordpress.com/2016/07/28/how-to-combine-box-and-jitter-plots-using-r-and-ggplot2/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
set.seed(123)
binary=sample(c(0,1),100,replace = T)
y = 10 + 2*binary + rnorm(100)
plot(y~binary,col=binary+1)
boxplot(y~binary,col=2:3)
```

[image]
[image]